# Exclusive Check-Out Not Working in Visual Studio 2022 with TFVC

Tags: azure-devops, visual-studio-2022, tfvc, source-control-explorer

We are using **Azure DevOps** with a **repo** that is set to **TFVC**.  I have configured the project in the following ways.

1.) I have set the **Workspace Settings** to "**SERVER**" by going to **Team Explorer -> Settings -> Source Control** as shown below.

[image: Workspace Settings]

2.) I have **UNCHECKED** the "**Enable multiple check-out**" checkbox in the **Check-out Settings** by going to **Team Explorer -> Settings -> Team Project -> Source Control** as shown below.

[image: Checkout Settings]

3.) I have configured my **Visual Studio Workspace** location to be "**Server**" as shown below.

[image: Workspace Settings]

We have triple checked these settings for all three members of the team and yet **we're still able to have multiple devs check-out the same file and edit it**.

[image: Multiple Checkouts]

I have a small team here and I want to **avoid merging code**.  What am I missing?  How can I get TFVC and Visual Studio to **prevent more than one person editing the same file at once**?

Comment: **Everyone** has to use a Server workspace for exclusive checkout to work. There's no way to enforce it.

Comment: @DanielMann We've triple checked this over and over.  ***However, the workspaces started as Local and then we changed them to Server.  If we check-in all of the code on all three workspaces, merge all of the code.  Delete the workspaces and create all of them from scratch as "Server", will this solve our problem?

Comment: It shouldn't make a difference. However, I can't say that I'm sure what would happen to anything checked out *before* you converted from a local workspace to a server workspace.

Comment: Any reason why you haven't migrated to GIT yet?

Comment: @PiersMyers we prefer TFVC and want to have exclusive locks.  It's a small team of 3.